# How did Paul Vitti know a cop will come and shoot him?

Tags: plot-explanation, analyze-that

In [***Analyze That***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0289848/), a cop came and tried to shoot Paul in his bed.

[image]

But Paul is lying under the bed in safety.

[image]

This means he knew the cop will come and try to shoot him. But who told him?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### There were clues.

Firstly there was the headline in the newspaper **"MOB SHRINK TELLS ALL"**.

Then his cellmate is transferred leaving him alone in his cell.

All of these are indications to a senior member of the mob that his life is in danger.

He may not have known *who* would come...but he knew *someone* would and prepared accordingly.